# PyTorch DataLoader: Only one element tensors can be converted Python scalars

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

For Python 3.10 and torch version: 1.12.1, I am using MNIST dataset scaled in the range [0, 1] with one-hot encoded vectors for the target as:

```
batch_size = 256

# Define transformations for MNIST dataset-
# MNIST dataset statistics-
# mean = np.array([0.1307])
# std_dev = np.array([0.3081])

transforms_apply = transforms.Compose(
    [
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        # transforms.Normalize(mean = mean, std = std_dev)
    ]
)

# Load MNIST dataset-
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
        root = 'data', train = True,
        transform = transforms_apply, download = True
        )

test_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
        root = 'data', train = False,
        transform = transforms_apply
        )

# Sanity check-
print(f"training dataset length/shape: {list(train_dataset.data.size())}")
# training dataset length/shape: [60000, 28, 28]

print(f"mean = {train_dataset.data.float().mean() / 255:.4f} &"
      f" std dev = {train_dataset.data.float().std() / 255:.4f}"
     )
# mean = 0.1307 & std dev = 0.3081

# Convert the targets to one-hot encoded vectors-
train_dataset.targets = F.one_hot(train_dataset.targets, num_classes = 10)
test_dataset.targets = F.one_hot(test_dataset.targets, num_classes = 10)

# Sanity checks-
print(f"Train dataset: min = {train_dataset.data.min()} & max = {train_dataset.data.max()};"
      f" Test dataset: min = {test_dataset.data.min()} & max = {test_dataset.data.max()}"
     )
# Train dataset: min = 0 & max = 255; Test dataset: min = 0 & max = 255

train_dataset.data.shape, train_dataset.targets.shape
# (torch.Size([60000, 28, 28]), torch.Size([60000, 10]))

test_dataset.data.shape, test_dataset.targets.shape
# (torch.Size([10000, 28, 28]), torch.Size([10000, 10]))

# Create training and testing dataloaders-
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset = train_dataset, batch_size = batch_size,
        shuffle = True
        )

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset = test_dataset, batch_size = batch_size,
        shuffle = False
        )

print(f"Sizes of train_dataset: {len(train_dataset)} and test_dataet: {len(test_dataset)}")
print(f"Sizes of train_loader: {len(train_loader)} and test_loader: {len(test_loader)}")
# Sizes of train_dataset: 60000 and test_dataet: 10000
# Sizes of train_loader: 235 and test_loader: 40

print(f"len(train_loader) = {len(train_loader)} & len(test_loader) = {len(test_loader)}")
# len(train_loader) = 235 & len(test_loader) = 40

# Sanity check-
len(train_dataset) / batch_size, len(test_dataset) / batch_size
# (234.375, 39.0625)

# Get some random batch of training images & labels-
x, y = next(iter(train_loader))
print(f"images.shape: {x.shape}, labels.shape: {y.shape}")
```

This generates the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) Input In [25], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Get some random batch of training images & labels-
----> 2 x, y = next(iter(train_loader))
      3 print(f"images.shape: {x.shape}, labels.shape: {y.shape}")

File ~\anaconda3\envs\torch-gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py:681, in _BaseDataLoaderIter.__next__(self)
    678 if self._sampler_iter is None:
    679     # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    680     self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 681 data = self._next_data()
    682 self._num_yielded += 1
    683 if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \
    684         self._IterableDataset_len_called is not None and \
    685         self._num_yielded > self._IterableDataset_len_called:

File ~\anaconda3\envs\torch-gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py:721, in _SingleProcessDataLoaderIter._next_data(self)
    719 def _next_data(self):
    720     index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 721     data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    722     if self._pin_memory:
    723         data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data, self._pin_memory_device)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\torch-gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py:49, in _MapDatasetFetcher.fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     47 def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     48     if self.auto_collation:
---> 49         data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     50     else:
     51         data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

File ~\anaconda3\envs\torch-gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py:49, in <listcomp>(.0)
     47 def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     48     if self.auto_collation:
---> 49         data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     50     else:
     51         data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

File ~\anaconda3\envs\torch-gpu\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\mnist.py:138, in MNIST.__getitem__(self, index)
    130 def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> Tuple[Any, Any]:
    131     """
    132     Args:
    133         index (int): Index    (...)
    136         tuple: (image, target) where target is index of the target class.
    137     """
--> 138     img, target = self.data[index], int(self.targets[index])
    140     # doing this so that it is consistent with all other datasets
    141     # to return a PIL Image
    142     img = Image.fromarray(img.numpy(), mode="L")

ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

I know that this is due to the one-hot encoding since when not using it, this error is absent. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to your transforms using the [`Lambda` transform](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.Lambda.html)

```
transforms_apply = transforms.Compose(
    [
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        # transforms.Normalize(mean = mean, std = std_dev)
        transforms.Lambda(lambda t: F.one_hot(t.long(), num_classes=10))
    ]
)
```